# criteria.list() returns two entries instead of one

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate criteria.list() returns two entries instead of one. In the database is only one entry for TaxTable with 2 corresponding TaxEntries. I think there is something wrong with the joins I do. Here is my code:
TaxTable:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tax_table")
public class TaxTable implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taxTable",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<TaxEntry> entries;
    ...
```

TaxEntry:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tax_entry")
public class TaxEntry implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal percentage;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account toAccount;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "taxtable_id")
    private TaxTable taxTable;
    ...
```

To fetch the result I use following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<TaxTable> findAll() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria taxTableCriteria = session.createCriteria(TaxTable.class);
    taxTableCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
    return taxTableCriteria.list();
}
```

In my test I create a TaxTable with 2 taxEntries:

```
...
taxEntryVAT.setTaxTable(taxTable);
taxEntryWT.setTaxTable(taxTable);
taxEntries.add(taxEntryVAT);
taxEntries.add(taxEntryWT);
taxTable.setEntries(taxEntries);
taxTableDao.create(taxTable);
```

And the fetch will return a list of 2 taxTables with the same id instead of one:

```
List<TaxTable> result = taxTableDao.findAll();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

Comment: Generally hibernate perform left outer join on table. So it will include all the rows from left table and matched rows from right result duplicate rows. By specifying Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY Hibernate will know not to include all from left only matched row can include in result. That's what I understood so far..for more info you can google .